# Telling ember-simple-auth that the user is now invalidated/logged-out, inside a custom authenticator

Tags: ember-simple-auth

From a custom authenticator; is there a way of telling ember-simple-auth that a user is now invalidated/logged-out?

Some background: I am building an authenticator with token refresh, similar to oauth2-password-grant. While I haven't experimented with the oauth2 authenticator directly, it seems we face the same issue: if the [token refresh fails to update](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/7c3dbd4118175563d44373f700ca5268a2176c5c/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js#L372), for example due to an expired token, the user remains logged in as far as ember-simple-auth is concerned.

EDIT: (to address comments for further clarification)
Ah, [I use JWTs and the server does not maintain sessions](https://github.com/myartsev/ember-simple-auth-jwt); the server has no idea who is logged in nor does it matter. The authentication is done via username/password after which the server issues a JWT token along with a time when it expires. To prolong the expiry time, you may refresh this token (as long as its valid) and get a new token with an updated expiry time. All is well and good except that ember-simple-auth *does* keep track of whether the user is logged in, as it should. However, if a call to refresh the token fails the user should be considered logged out (the token is invalid/expired and any attempts to make a call to an API that requires authentication will fail).
My question is how do I tell ember-simple-auth that this user has been logged out.

Comment: I am confused. Don't you use token to authenticate to the server? If the token in invalid (expired, not refreshed), how could the server authenticate you? You are effectively logged out. Does the server maintain a session? If so, can't you call server to explicitly log out? But either way it seems *the server side* is not correctly designed.

Comment: Did you figure this out? You should call invalidate from wherever you're checking the result of the refresh. This will clear the local session created by ESA.